# When adding rows to a new sheet using the Smartsheet Node.js SDK. how would you indent one of the rows you are adding?

Tags: node.js, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

First time posting here, so I apologize for any "grievances" and appreciate your patience. I'm working on a process that creates new sheet, and then parses an array of row Objects to be added to the new sheet.

https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/#operation/rows-addToSheet

The area I'm struggling with is including a property to indent the row being added. The indent property is indicated in the specify row location resource in the documentation.

https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/#section/Specify-Row-Location

Here is what i thought my row object should look like:

```
const myRowObj = [
  {
    toBottom: true,
    cells: [
      {
        columnId: 3811134080870276,
        value: 'no indent',
      },
      {
        columnId: 8314733708240772,
        value: "this line has no indent"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    toBottom: true,
    indent: 1,
    cells: [
      {
        columnId: 3811134080870276,
        value: 'indent sent to 1'
      },
      {
        columnId: 8314733708240772,
        value: "this line has an indent"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

... however when using this row Object, I get an error back indicating that indent should be used by itself in a request.

```
{
  statusCode: 400,
  errorCode: 1062,
  message: "Invalid row location: Use 'indent' by itself. You cannot use other location specifiers in the same request.",
  refId: '9abmoi4dizfj',
  detail: { index: 0 }
}
```

... when using the above code, and leaving out the `indent` property, the rows are successfully processed, but no indentation takes place obviously. When removing the `toBottom` properties from each row and using `indent` in the second row instead, i get a new error:

```
{
  statusCode: 400,
  errorCode: 1123,
  message: 'Specifying multiple row locations is not yet supported. Each row must use the same row location attribute and value (toBottom, toTop, parentId, siblingId, 
above)',
  refId: 'wbpkbx4qw7oz',
  detail: { index: 1 }
}
```

This, of course, contradicts the original instruction for the first error. Including the `indent` property on both rows, returns the first error. So, after spending around 4 hours trying to fidget with this much needed feature, I wanted to ask if anyone else has had success using the `indent` property when adding rows to a sheet. I'm hoping someone could share a sample of how the row object with an indent is structured,  since the documentation lacks a working sample.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Don V.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a few things to understand about specifying row location:

- By default, new rows are added to the bottom of the sheet -- so it's not necessary to specify the `toBottom` property if you want new rows to be added to the bottom of the sheet.
- The `indent` property can only be used to specify indent level for existing rows in a sheet -- you can't use it in a request that adds new rows to a sheet.
- When using the **Add Rows** operation to add new rows to a sheet, all new rows specified in the request must use the same [row location specifier attributes](https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/#section/Specify-Row-Location). This means that you can't use a single **Add Rows** request to add a parent row and a child row indented under that row all at the same time -- because those rows are in different *locations* (one is indented, the other is not).

So, let's say you have a sheet that already contains some rows:

[image: initial sheet]

If you want add two rows to the bottom of a sheet, where the first row is a parent row (with no indentation) and the second row is a child row (*with* indentation), then you'll need to do so as a 2-step process (i.e., 2 separate **Add Row(s)** requests):

**Step 1 (add parent row):**

Issue the **Add Rows** request to add the first row (with no indentation).

```
POST https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/3932034054809476/rows

[
    {
        "cells": [
            {
                "columnId": 6101753539127172,
                "value": 4
            },
            {
                "columnId": 5228827298293636,
                "value": "parent row (no indent)"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

After this request is issued, the sheet contains this new row (no indentation):

[image: sheet with one new row]

**Step 2 (add child row):**

The API response from the previous **Add Row(s)** request will contain the ID of the row that it added:

[image: Add Row response with id property highlighted]

When you issue the next **Add Row(s)** request, you'll specify this ID value as the `parentId` for the row you're adding -- this is how you tell Smartsheet to add the new row as a child (i.e., indented) row under the specified row.

```
POST https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/sheets/3932034054809476/rows

[
    {
        "parentId": 7046650170566532,
        "cells": [
            {
                "columnId": 6101753539127172,
                "value": 5
            },
            {
                "columnId": 5228827298293636,
                "value": "child row (with indent)"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

After this request is issued, the sheet contains the new child (i.e., indented) row:

[image: sheet with new child (indented) row added]

Hope this is helpful. If you need additional clarification please add a comment to this answer; if this successfully addresses your question, please mark this answer as *accepted* (so that others are more likely to benefit from this info in the future). Thanks!